# Windows can't find the file on subprocess.call()

Tags: python, path, python-3.x

I am getting the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

My code is:

```
subprocess.call(["<<executable file found in PATH>>"])
```

Windows 7, 64 bit. Python 3.x latest, stable.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: and what is this executable file?

Comment: The "android" executable part of the Android SDK

Comment: And is *is* available on PATH

Comment: can you run it from the command line?

Comment: A little background of what I'm trying to accomplish. This is for Opendevice - an open source project to convert HTML5 apps into device specific apps.

I'm trying to replace os.system() in http://bitbucket.org/srirangan/opendevice/src/tip/tools/net/srirangan/opendevice/plugins/AndroidPlugin.py to subprocess.call()

Comment: @SilentGhost: Yes I can run it from the command line. os.sys("...") calls in Python also work.

Comment: If the path has spaces, is it quoted? And of course, you escaped backslashes properly, or used slashes, right?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

When the command is a shell built-in, add a `shell=True` to the call.

E.g. for `dir` you would type:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
```

To quote from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> The only time you need to specify `shell=True` on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. **dir** or **copy**). You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch file or console-based executable.

Comment: That's because there's no executable called `dir.exe` while there's a `/bin/ls` in *nix. `dir` is implemented by _CMD.EXE_ much like `cd` is implemented by _bash_.

Comment: This is strongly discouraged. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: @nueverest Only when the _the command string is constructed from external input_

Comment: The alternative (more secure for external input) is to get the `PATH` from the `os.environ` and search it manually.

Answer (score 50):

On Windows, I believe the [`subprocess` module doesn't look in the `PATH` unless you pass `shell=True`](https://bugs.python.org/issue17023) because it use `CreateProcess()` behind the scenes. However, `shell=True` can be a security risk if you're passing arguments that may come from outside your program. To make `subprocess` nonetheless able to find the correct executable, you can use [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which). Suppose the executable in your `PATH` is named `frob`:

```
subprocess.call([shutil.which('frob'), arg1, arg2])
```

(This works on Python 3.3 and above.)

Comment: Any python 2 option?

Comment: @Naramsim Try `from distutils.spawn import find_executable as which`. This line is copied from pre-commit's hook script.

Comment: This is not correct. The system examines the `PATH` even without `shell=True` but shell built-ins like `cd` and `dir` are not available on the `PATH` because they are not executables at all. That's what being built into the shell means; the command is understood and executed by the shell itself, and does not exist as a separate binary.

Answer (score 27):

On Windows you have to call through cmd.exe. As Apalala mentioned, Windows commands are implemented in cmd.exe not as separate executables.

e.g.

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'dir'])
```

/c tells cmd to run the follow command

This is safer than using shell=True, which allows shell injections.

Comment: How would I keep the screen open?

Comment: @Moondra, If I understand you correctly, try `/k` instead of `/c`. Enter `cmd /?` at the command line for details.

Comment: This answer helped me when getting WinError 5 permission denined on Windows 10 using powershell

Comment: This is just a roundabout way of reimplementing `shell=True`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using powershell, then in it will be `subprocess.call(['powershell','-command','dir'])`. Powershell supports a large portion of POSIX commands

Comment: `dir` is not a POSIX command, though.

Answer (score 2):

After much head scratching, I discovered that running a file that is located in C:\Windows\System32\ while running a 32bit version of python on a 64bit machine is a potential issue, due to Windows trying to out-smart the process, and redirect calls to C:\Windows\System32 to C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

I found an example of how to fix this here:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578035-disable-file-system-redirector/

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the documentation:

"Prior to Python 3.5, these three functions comprised the high level API to subprocess. You can now use run() in many cases, but lots of existing code calls these functions."

SO: instead of subprocess.call use subprocess.run for Python 3.5 and above

Comment: This is good advice _per se,_ but does nothing to solve the actual question here.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue while I was calling a PHP. The reason is PHP isn't in PATH so the command PHP was not found. But PowerShell found it does exist in the current location and it suggests replacing the 'PHP' by the '.\PHP' if I trust this command. Then it runs well.