# Error while installing pycdio-0.2 for Python 3.5 "[WinError2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: python, powershell, python-3.x, audio

I'm a bit new to installing Python modules. I'm trying to use Windows Powershell to install pycdio for Python 3.5 64-bit and this is what appears.

`PS C:\Users\vivek\Desktop\audio converter python\pycdio-0.20> python     ./setup.py install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./setup.py", line 42, in 
        ge_84 = call(['pkg-config','--atleast-version=0.84','libcdio'])
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 560, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in init
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in     _execute_child
        startupinfo)`

I've also tried 32-bit, but still get the same error. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Since it's failing on that line, make certain you have the [prerequisites](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycdio/#requirements) installed. If you do, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616867/792032), since you're on Windows try editing line 42 to be ```ge_84 = call(['pkg-config','--atleast-version=0.84','libcdio'], shell=True)``` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, I followed your steps. The error still remains and I also get <code>ImportError: No module named 'pykg_config'</code>
I have installed pykg-config

Comment: If you've installed it and it's saying it can't find pykg_config, then it sounds like your [python path](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) isn't set up. Try and verify that is working first.

Comment: I've checked the path in environment variables. The Python 3.5 folder is listed in the path, along with the Python lib folder and SWIG.

Comment: Apologies for the very slow reply.

Comment: Where is the pykg_config module located in your filesystem, and can you paste your current PYTHONPATH environmental variable?

Comment: It is located in: C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Lib\site-packages\pykg_config

Comment: That directory is in the PATH variable. I haven't made a PYTHONPATH variable