# Windows: Python subprocess "can't find the file specified" when using PostGres

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, subprocess, pytest

I am using the package [pytest-server-fixtures](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-server-fixtures/) for tests using a PostGres database on Windows. 
The problem arises in the package when trying to access pg_config.exe:

```
subprocess.check_output(["pg_config", "--bindir"])
```

The error given:

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I know this is a relatively common error, but no other answers addressed the issue.

Things I have tried:
• pg_config.exe exists in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin, and this has been added to my PATH.
• Running `pg_config --bindir` outside of Python returns a path. 
• Running `check_output` with `shell=True` is unsuccessful.
• Running `check_output` with `shutil.which('pg_config')` is unsuccessful.
• psycopg2 was installed AFTER PostGres was installed.
• Tried with psycopg2-binary unsuccessfully.
• These tests were written on MacOS, and are successfully being run there and on Linux.
• pg_config.exe has read and execute permissions.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `env = os.environ.copy(); subprocess.check_output(..., env=env)`?

Comment: @hoefling Same error, unfortunately...

Comment: Then check whether you will find a useful answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3022013/2650249